# APN Settings for O2 service in UK + Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, apn

I am developing an application which requires connection to the  internet. Till now i have been using Wifi and WAP 2 connection UID for Http connection and everything has been working fine. But now the client is telling that he wishes to use direct TCP connection as  using WAP2.0 connection costs him a big amount. 
I am not having clear understanding about APN settings. I have goggled a bit and appended 'deviceside=true'  to the url and then set the APN in the Settings->Advanced Options->TCP/IP. But everytime I run the application, I am getting 'Timed Out' Exception. 
My client is using O2 carrier. I googled and found out that APN for 2 are 'mobile.o2.co.uk'  and 'wap.o2.co.uk'  but using  these two also client is not able to make Http connection. Is there any way of free unlimited internet connectivity in third party applications? 
I am not having a clear understanding of APN settings so kindly bear with me. I am using OS 4.5

Eargerly waiting for reply.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the confusing world of network transports on BlackBerry!  You will want to start with the article [Connecting your BlackBerry - http and socket connections to the world](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242).

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanx for the reply. I have read the above link but still could not glean much from it. I appended 'deviceside=true'as mentioned in the above link for Tcp connection and set the correct APN value in TCP/IP but still i am getiing Timed Out exception.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any answers for that, but I can give some questions that might spur you in the right direction: are you sure that you have the right APN information for the carrier on the device you are using?  Are you sure that the carrier allows use of the network transport in the way that you have configured it?  Do you need to have a different data plan from the carrier in order to enable different network transports?

Comment: Thanx Scott , your reply did help me.